# Practical applications of dimensionality reduction methods: Filtering, Wrapper, Embedded models

Tags: data-mining, dimensionality-reduction

Filtering is basically sorting some features and picking top performing ones. Where wrapper in wrapper we go through unused/used features add/remove some of them and test performance over validation. I am expecting wrapper to perform better learning. Where filtering is simple to implement and less costly.

And there is another one, that I have no idea: Embedded.

Can someone provide some real-life examples and use-cases of these methods? It would be perfect if someone give some detailed information about embedded method.

Comment: Can you please provide source of your terms filtering, wrapper and embedded?

Comment: @Alexey , I just summarized my knowledge over those concepts. Check this page for detailed informaton http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection